# C# Lync/Skype for Business chatbot auto message

Tags: c#, lync

I have a working bot, but I want to figure out on how to initiate the conversation by my bot, when her profile in Skype for Business is clicked and showing the chat conversation, like she will instantly message the user "Hello!". The line of code below is the one sends the message, but it needs the user's credential to response.

Is it possible?

```
msgUIInstance.BeginSendMessage("Hello", null, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

We would call that a proactive bot.
[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot) is a Sample of Auto initializing bot.

you can take a look at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages), where you will find simpler examples on how to send proactive messages.